# Best way or algorithm to near duplicate check against huge list of files?

Tags: python, performance, indexing, deduplication

I am using python to neardupe huge list of file (over 20000 ) files. Totaling about 300 MB

Current way is to do near-dupe checking using difflib's SequenceMatcher and getting result using QuickRatio .

With 4 worker process it takes 25 hours to get the job done , which is quite slow.

I also tried Livenstheine which gives C base near-dupe checking but its even slower and less accurate than difflib.

The checking need to be done in this manner : 
There are 20000 files in a folder. each file need to compare against 20000 files in the folder on every iterations. so there will be 20000 * 20000 iterations.

What I think of is to index all the files and comparing indexes but i am new to indexing and i am not sure it would work. If that the way what is the best indexing options?

Thanks.

Below is the code :

```
import os,sys,chardet, csv,operator,time,subprocess
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
import threading
#from threading import Timer
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool

OrgFile = ""
mark = int(sys.argv[2])

def init_logger():
    print "Starting %s" % multiprocessing.current_process().name

#----Get_Near_DupeStatus--------#
def Get_Near_DupeStatus(score):
    if score > 30 and score <= 50:
        return "Low Inclusive"
    elif score > 50 and score <= 75:
        return "Inclusive"
    elif score > 75 and score <= 85:
        return "Most Inclusive"
    elif score > 85 and score <= 99:
        return "Near-Dupe"
    elif score == 100:
        return "Unique"
    else: return "No Inclusive"

#----Write_To_CSV --- ALL-------#
def Write_To_CSV_All(List):
    writer = csv.writer(open('./TableList.csv','wb'),delimiter=';', quotechar=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow(['Path/FileName(Source);'+'ID;'+'NearDupeID;'+'Similarity Score;'+'Near_DupeStatus;'+'NearDupeProcess(Y/N);'+'Encoding'])
    for i,li in enumerate(sorted(List, key=operator.itemgetter("NearDupeID"))):
        writer.writerow([li['Path/FileName(Source)']+";"+'ID00'+str(i+1)+";"+str(li['NearDupeID'])+";"+str(li['Similarity Score'])+";"+li['Near_DupeStatus']+";"+li['NearDupeProcess(Y/N)']+";"+li['Encoding']])

#Get Finish File List
def Finish_Files(List,count,id):
    finish_files = []
    for i,li in enumerate(sorted(List, key=operator.itemgetter("Similarity Score"), reverse=True)):
        if i < count:
            li['NearDupeID'] = id
            finish_files.append(li)
        if count == 0:
            li['NearDupeID'] = id
#            if li['Similarity Score'] > 50:
            finish_files.append(li)
    return finish_files

#----Search Files in Dir--------#
def GetFileListFrom_Dir(dir):
    FileList = []
    for root,dirs,filenames in os.walk(dir):
        for filename in filenames:
            realpath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            FileList.append(realpath)
    return FileList

#----Matcher--------#
def Matcher(realpath):
    junk = ["\t","\n","\r"]
    score = 0
    dict = {}
    MatchFile = ""
    dupe_Process = 'N'
    if os.path.isfile(realpath):
        MatchFile =  open(realpath).read()
        matcher = SequenceMatcher(lambda x: x in junk,OrgFile, MatchFile)
        score = int(matcher.ratio()*100)
        if score >= mark:
            encoding = chardet.detect(MatchFile)['encoding']
            if encoding == None: encoding = 'None'
            if score > 85: dupe_Process = 'Y'
            dict = {'Path/FileName(Source)':realpath,'Similarity Score':score,'Near_DupeStatus':Get_Near_DupeStatus(score),'NearDupeProcess(Y/N)':dupe_Process,'Encoding':encoding}
            return dict

#-------------Pooling--------------------#
def MatcherPooling(FileList,orgFile,process):
    global OrgFile
    OrgFile = open(orgFile).read()
    pool_obj = Pool(processes=process)
    #pool_obj = Pool(processes=process,initializer=init_logger)
    dict = {}
    DictList = []
    dict = pool_obj.map(Matcher,FileList)
    DictList.append(dict)
    pool_obj.close()
    pool_obj.join()
    return DictList

def Progress():
    p = "/-\\|"
#    global t
    for s in p:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        sys.stdout.write("%c" % s)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sys.stdout.write('\b')
    t2 = threading.Timer(0.1,Progress).start()
#    t.start()


#----Main--------#
def Main():
    Mainls = []
    dictList = []
    finish_List = []
    BLINK = '\033[05m'
    NOBLINK = '\033[25m'
    dir = sys.argv[1]
    process = int(sys.argv[3])
    Top_rec = int(sys.argv[4])
    Mainls = GetFileListFrom_Dir(dir)
    bar = "*"
    # setup toolbar
    sys.stdout.write("%s" % BLINK+"Processing...."+ NOBLINK + "With "+ str(process) + " Multi Process...")#+" \n")
    if Top_rec != 0:
        charwidth = len(Mainls)/Top_rec
    elif Top_rec == 0: charwidth = len(Mainls)
    t = threading.Timer(0.1,Progress)
    t.start()
#    sys.stdout.write("[%s]" % ("-" * charwidth))
#    sys.stdout.flush()
#    sys.stdout.write("\b" * (charwidth+1)) # return to start of line, after '['

    #----------------------------------------------------------#
    for id,orgFile in enumerate(sorted(Mainls)):
        for dl in MatcherPooling(sorted(Mainls),orgFile,process):
            for dict in dl:
                if dict != None:
                    dictList.append(dict)

            #Append Finish Files List For CSV ALL(Write Once)
            fl = Finish_Files(dictList,Top_rec,id+1)
            if Top_rec != 0:
                for del_List in fl:
                    Mainls.remove(del_List['Path/FileName(Source)'])
                    Mainls.sort()

            finish_List.extend(fl)
            dictList = []

        sys.stdout.write("%s" % bar)
        sys.stdout.flush()

        #Exit Loop
        if len(Mainls) == 0:
            break
    #----------------------------------------------------------#
    Write_To_CSV_All(finish_List)
    #print os.system('clear')
    sys.stdout.write("%s" % " ")
    print "Finished!"
    t.cancel()
    print os._exit(99)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: Why do you want to compare them that way? Are you trying to build classes of near-duplicate files?

Comment: Are the files of a specific type? Do you what kind of differences and similarities to expect?

Comment: What i want is duplicity score one file is how much % duplicate for other file , digital forensics stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partial answer, but one obvious optimization is to only compare files with approximately the same size. Also comparing file a and file b is the same as comparing b and a: 20000 files gives 20000 * (20000-1)/2 comparisons.
300 MB is not that big, you could try to read in all files first.

On indexing, it's just about describing each file with one ore more numbers. Size is one. Number of non-white space or white space or new line characters could be others. If the files all contain the same kind of data you can interpret the data to create more useful numbers.
Also, completely identical files will have the same SHA-256 hash. This will only help if a significant fraction of the files are identical.

```
import hashlib
m = hashlib.sha256()
m.update(file_contents)
this_files_hash_value=m.digest()
```

Unfortunately I can think of no method for completely accurately and correctly factorizing (parts of) what is done by `difflib.SequenceMatcher` since it's dynamically comparing all possible chunks of the input files.

Comment: With hashing de-duplication is very fast but what i want is near-duplicate with scores . like 1 file is how much Percent duplicate of another file. so yes i can use hashing to get duplicated files , remove them first and re-calculate ,. it will be fast for files with many total duplicates but just near-dupes wont work.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by, as mentioned here, only comparing files that are relatively close in size or similar in MIME type.

then I'd continue by comparing just a small portion of the data to rule out most cases immediately.
A nice algorithm would start with a small chunk of the files, compare it, increase the size by a factor of 2 (or more if you want) if it's similar enough, and so forth until you finish comparing everything, or until at any stage the similarity factor is too low.

this means probably the first 1-2 iterations will rule out most files.

Answer (score 0):

**First of all you should know if your procedure is as fast as it can be.**

- Time an average execution time that it takes to compare 2 files. Just compare them, don't use multiprocessing, don't index nothing, don't write to csv nothing.
- Multiply that for `20000 x 10000 / 4` (since you have 4 workers)
- Compare the result you get with yours current 25 hours.

I believe that this is a very important test because it will show if there's still room for improvement with your current comparing algorithm.

If there's room for improvement than start to do that! Because once you'll have an optimezied procedure, you'll be able to move on and start looking for a better comparing solution.

If you want to ask help on how to do that, you'll have to provide a more readable code example (and short), because it's impossible to work on what you have right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with big collections and you want to find not only duplicates, but also near-duplicates within text based files (PDF, DOC, HTML, etc.), you might need to think about something like this:
http://softcorporation.com/products/neardup/
It is Java based, so will work in different platforms, and you can download it free.